# Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project - include VC++ 2015 Redistributable

Tags: visual-studio-2017, installation, redistributable, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am creating the installer for my application using a "Visual Studio Installer" project type in Visual Studio 2017.

I want my installer to install visual c++ redistributable 2015 with my application.   I've downloaded the `vc_redist.x86.exe` file, included it in my project, and I'm trying to do the install as a custom action on "install".  I am launching with the arguments `/install /passive /norestart`.

When I execute my installer, when it does the custom action, I get this error:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.  A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.  Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I can run `vc_redist.x86.exe /install /passive /norestart` at the command prompt with no problem or errors.

Any suggestions or alternative ways to include Visual C++ redistributable as part of my install?

Answer (score 5):

You can't run that redistributable as a custom action because it's an MSI-based install, and you cannot run recursive MSI installs (yours calling the VC redist one).

In Visual Studio setup projects you're supposed to use the Prerequisites feature. Right-click the setup project in Solution Explorer, choose Properties, then Prerequisites. This will build a setup.exe to install prerequisites followed by your MSI file. As far as I can tell, the Microsoft Visual C++ 14 is the Visual Studio 2015 runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Recommendation***: Migrate to [WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) Burn (bootstrapper / downloader / sequencer) to allow more future flexibility and control (WiX links below).
>
> Alternatively try the **prerequisites** section below first (select the "`Visual Studio 14`" entries for install) or try the  **merge modules** available (section below). Please pay attention to the disclaimers for the merge modules.
>
> - [WiX Burn XML Markup Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275683/129130%C2%A8).
> - [**WiX Burn Information & Simple Markup Sample**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130) - with lots of links for further information.
> - [WiX - Install Prerequisites and 3rd party applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839600/wix-install-prerequisites-and-3rd-party-applications)

---

***Logging & Mutex***: What does the log file say? From a technical point of view the usual problem is that  you can not install another MSI package from within your own running MSI setup due to technical runtime restrictions. A mutex is set to prevent several MSI installation transactions to happen at once. Check the logs. This redistributable is MSI-based I believe - so you will see this problem when running the EXE from a custom action like you do.

***Deployment Tools***: Visual Studio Installer Projects are very limited, and it seems most people migrate away from them to another deployment tool over time. [Maybe have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976968/129130) - and [here is a list of tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). WiX's Burn feature (bootstrapper / downloader / sequencer) can achieve what you need. [Also read PhilDW's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977260/129130).

***Prerequisites***: Visual Studio Installer Projects do have [a prerequisites view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706684/129130) (click the `Prerequisites...` button) where a limited number of prerequisites can be defined for installation via the **`setup.exe`** bootstrapper (not kicked off from within your MSI itself, but from its bootstrapper setup.exe - this means you don't kick off the install from within your own MSI, but before it starts to install - and it can hence work correctly). I am not sure if the entries for "`Visual Studio 14`" are for the runtime version you need. You could give it a try I suppose.

***Merge Modules***: There are merge modules to install the Visual Studio Runtime ([see here, section "Visual C++ Runtime"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2015-redistribution-vs#-distributable-code-files-for-visual-studio-2015) - quite a bit down the page), but they seem inadequate these days [for reasons explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423249/129130) (very important). Essentially the Visual Studio Runtime is more complicated from 2015 onwards - and the EXE installer is preferred. Must read link - please. In order to locate relevant merge modules, please search for *.msm files underneath **`%ProgramFiles(x86)%`** - if you have Visual Studio (and / or the Windows SDK) installed. **`Merge modules can be installed embedded in your own package without the need for a setup.exe launcher`**. In Visual Studio, right click your installer project, `Add`, then `Merge Module...`

Comment: This is not answering anyting, its suggesting something else.

Comment: To me VS installer projects are too limited: [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130) ([short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637666/129130)). Sometimes you want to warn people that the approach they use lead them into bear traps. See the "Prerequisites" section above - you can install the VC++ runtime for your VS version using this feature, but it is very limited. WiX / Burn can install anything you want. [Pillage github.com for samples](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=vc_redist.x86.exe+ExePackage+%3CWix&type=Code).